# Tablet is not coming up Landscape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tablet (iBall - http://www.iball.co.in/Product/3G-1026-Q18/745) - Strangely I don't get landscape it is always taking portrait even after I have given:

layout-large-land

layout-xlarge-land

layout

it is already taking the XML from layout folder?

How to solve this issue?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: is screen orientation option enable from settings ?

Comment: Well, Other App's automatically come up with landscape mode.

Comment: I double checked they are enabled.

Comment: do you have layout in res/layout-land? and make sure your manifest does not forced to use portrait (See `android:screenOrientation`)

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara - if I put the layout in layout-land then on phones it will show up as land. I would like show phones in portrait and tablets as landscape.. BTW: In manifest I have given: android:screenOrientation="nosensor"

Answer (score 1):

If you use `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` then I believe system will choose orientation for you but without reference to physical orientation sensor (display will not rotate when user move device) and will use default natural orientation of device. In your case, maybe it is portrait.

Comment: My suggestion is to remove attribute `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` and create more spesific layout for this particular device. For example create res/layout-large with content same as landscape layout. When on phone, res/layout will be used, but on tablet (portrait or landscape) res/layout-large or res/layout-large-land will be used

Comment: If I do that How do I restrict the app not to goto Portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use layout-sw600dp-land folder instead of layout-large-land as shortest width is 600 for this tablet.

Comment: have you tried on any other tablet? if yes, can you share some more info how are you working in implementation?

Comment: As in the question I have create layout-xlarge-land: main.xml - Main.java doesn't have anything.. When I open the app on Nexus 10 or Samsung Galaxy Note 3 tab 10.1 inch - they automatically take layout-xlarge-land version.